# The function of the stopwatch sleep my entire program and my progress bar doesnt fill out

Tags: vb.net, benchmarking

Im currently working on a software that measure fps and gpu, cpu and ram scores.
For the fps test i start a stopwatch that sleeps the entire program, but i need to get at the same time a progress bar filling out, but the stopwatch function sleep the entire thing. If you have any idea to counter that, please help me out!
Thanks and sorry for my english skill issues...

```
Dim bmp As New Bitmap(Me.Width, Me.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb)
        Dim g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)
        Dim stopwatch As New Stopwatch()
        Dim frames As Integer = 0

        'Mesure du nombre de FPS pendant 5 secondes'
        stopwatch.Start()
        Do While stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds < 5
            g.DrawString(frames.ToString(), New Font("Arial", 12), Brushes.White, 0, 0)
            frames += 1
        Loop
        stopwatch.Stop()

        'Calcul du nombre de FPS moyen'
        Dim fps As Integer = frames \ 5

        'Affichage du nombre de FPS moyen'
        BunifuTextBox1.Text = fps.ToString()

        Return fps
```

I started to see whats going on with my progress bar but nothing happens

Comment: It's nothing to do with the `Stopwatch`. You have a loop that does nothing but draw text onto an `Image` for 5 seconds. Why would you expect anything else to happen while that loop is executing? I don't see anything related to a `ProgressBar` in that code. You need to do a better job of explaining what you're actually trying to achieve.

Comment: Remember that if you're executing on the UI thread, as long as your code is executing, the UI won't be able to do any updates.